# What "degrees" of consideration are there?

Tags: adverbs, collocation

> I am seriously considering taking English lessons

Are there other degrees of consideration that are a little less *serious*?

Comment: "strongly"? "really"?

Comment: Replace "seriously consider" by "*envisage*" or, to weaken even more the statement, use "*the possibility of taking English lessons*"

Comment: Tentatively, carelessly, frivolously, stupidly, witlessly, casually, ironically, dubiously, definitely -- how many do you want?

Comment: Good question... "how does one consider".  There must be a hierarchy of consideration... from whimsical to deadly serious.  The above is a good list.

Comment: I do not recall anyone saying anything else but: "You should seriously consider...", and "I am considering...". Not to say that I have never read anything else.

Comment: Offhand, the only "weakening" modifiers I can think of are the colloquial/slangy ***vaguely** considering* and perhaps ***kinda** considering*. Stretching a point, maybe ***idly considering***.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the seriously, that way you aren't using a weak word with seriously.

Comment: But you would use the continuous "I am considering taking..." wouldn't you? Or "I shall consider..."

Comment: *I am considering taking...* is just fine.  It means *I am thinking about taking...*